# How to find documents in mongodb collection which has a field with 2 values?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have field in mongodb collection with name status and it has 3 values Pending, Approved and Reapplied.
How do I get all documents with either Pending or Reapplied status?

Comment: post the schema or collection structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

status:{$in:["Pending","Reapplied"]}

Comment: Could you explain this a bit?

Comment: As per the other comment above, in the absence for further details re the collection, it's hard to give much further - however in a simple find query (assuming the field status isn't at a sub doc level) this condition will return both status...